# replace all column values equal to one string with another string

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a MYSQL table called traceclasses and I have a column in this table called `value` with some of its cell values equal to E as shown below. I would like to replace all such values with U. Which query should I use to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `update`:

```
update t
    set value = 'U'
    where value = 'E';
```